# Using JDBC with two developers via Dropbox

Tags: jdbc, dropbox, derby

I am a computer science student and my project partner and I are working on a project where we are required to develop a DB (JDBC) for our software. We are capable of doing this, but have hit a brick wall right out of the gates. Our entire project is stored on our shared access dropbox account so we can work on the same classes etc. This has been fine until we attempt to develop a DB that is stored on dropbox. Each time we attempt to open our project in our IDE we receive an issue to resolve: Cannot find derby.jar
Because of this, we each create conflicting path names to the project's derby file, as dropbox is stored on each of our separate machines. e.g "C:..\DropBox\Project\derbyclient.jar"
This in turn prevents each other's IDEs synchronizing with the DB we created.
What a mess, any help (or alternative approaches) would be greatly appreciated.
Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making sure your dropbox folders have the exact same path on both computers. This might involv one of you to re-install or reconfigure Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using real source control, like Subversion, Git, Mercurial etc. That is also handy if you need to go back to an earlier version of the code. And it is also great to document changes.